# invalidateOptionsMenu doesn't work in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

**Show or hide items in the `ActionBar` based on whether there is text in the `EditText` or not.**

So, I did the following

```java
public class NounSearch extends android.app.Fragment 
{
    EditText seachEditText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nounsearchactivity, container, false);

        // Intiate EditText
        seachEditText =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nounSearch);
        seachEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    searchResult.Entities = new ArrayList<NounModel>();
                    _currentPage = 0;
                    categoryId = -1;
                    new GetNouns().execute();
                    return true;
                }
                
                
                return false;
            }
        });

        seachEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                // ...
            }
        
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                    // ...
            }
        
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        
        if (seachEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0){
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

However the `ActionItem` never appear. **How can I achieve this?**

Comment: is the else part where the `invalidateOptionsMenu` located is executed?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I modified the code , and yes it fire but never call onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: can you post the entire class

Answer (score 75, accepted):

For updating the `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside the fragment you need to call the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside the `onCreate` method of the fragment. Otherwise you won't be able to update it when you call  `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();`

**sample:**

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

EDIT:

```java
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    if(seachEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it now works fine , but the item not appear any idea how to fix that

Comment: @AMH try to place the if and else statement before `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);`

Comment: Sorry how to do that please

Comment: thanks a lot works fine :) it will help me in the other parts

Comment: You should still add ``inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_layout, menu)`` before the ``if`` statement for this to work properly.

Comment: this is really helful :)

Comment: I just realised I came to this comment three times :)) The second one gave +1, now leaving this comment. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: menu options should be modified in onPrepareOptionsMenu, not onCreateOptionsMenu.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    if (seachEditText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1**

This is work in fragment

```
 getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

**Solution 2**

Try this if above code is not working

```
invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());
```

Import this library

```
import static androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu;
```