# Trying to hide a menuitem in Android, not behaving as expected

Tags: android, menu

I have the below menu item created and is showing always as an action, instead of being hidden in an overflow menu.

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh_network"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_action_refresh_network"
    android:title="@string/title_refresh_network"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

I need it to be hidden when `ThreshVoteIntentService.mOpportunistic` is `TRUE`. I have a receiver which is alerted by intent when that value has changed. It's a very simple procedure that invalidates the menu.

```
IntentFilter filterModeUpdated = new IntentFilter(resources.getString(R.string.action_mode_updated));
mModeUpdatedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

this.registerReceiver(mModeUpdatedReceiver, filterModeUpdated);
```

I have my options menu then (supposedly) redraw in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh_network).setVisible(ThreshVoteIntentService.mOpportunistic);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**What actually happens** is that the visibility of `menu_refresh_network` only changes when I open the overflow menu. Have I basically misunderstood how this should work?

Comment: try changing return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); to return true

Comment: Made no difference. :(

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25216064/1320616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onPrepareOptionsMenu() is only called, as you say, just before the overflow menu is show, so that's too late.

You need to call setVisible(false) on the correct MenuItem *before* invalidating the options menu.  So in your onCreateOptionsMenu(), find a reference to the MenuItem with [findItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int)) for the item id that you want to change and store that in a member variable.  Then, when the broadcast arrives, change the visibility of that item and then invalidate the options menu.

Here is a sample activity based off a new project I created in Android Studio to demonstrate this.  If you run this, you can see that the menu item disappears after 5 seconds, and no invalidate is even required to force the menu to refresh.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MenuItem menuItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Hide the menu item in 5 seconds
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                menuItem.setVisible(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've done that, and now the menu item is always visible, it never hides.

Comment: The strategy works just fine.  I updated my answer with sample code that I created in a new project that demonstrates how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AppCompatActivity` (as `app:showAsAction` implies), you should use [supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()) in place of `invalidateOptionsMenu()` as `invalidateOptionsMenu()` does not know about always visible action items (hence, why it only calls `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` when the menu is opened)

Comment: As suggested, I changed to `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`, however, it made no difference.